# Imported blender model rotates incorrectly

Tags: ios, swift, blender, scenekit

I've imported a Blender 3D model (a sphere with an Earth texture) in SceneKit, and I'm trying to rotate it through a pan gesture. I have to mentally swap the x and y axises, because the rotation system in SceneKit is different from the one adopted by Blender.

This is how I rotate the Earth object:

```
func pan(gesture:UIPanGestureRecognizer)
{
    let translation = gesture.translation(in: self.view) * 0.05
    let intensity = Float(magnitude(point: translation)) // Euclidean distance

    let rotation = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(intensity, Float(translation.y), Float(translation.x), 0.0) // I invert the x and y because of the different coordinate system
    earth.transform = SCNMatrix4Mult(earth.transform, rotation)

    gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint(x:0.0, y:0.0), in: self.view)
}
```

The rotation around the y axis is correct, but if I try to rotate it along the x axis by panning vertically, it seems like if the x axis of the Earth is oblique and not perpendicular with the y axis.

In this video I first drag the finger upwards and then downwards:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YumAB_rXlk

Comment: is it possible you can rotate the camera around the object instead of rotating the model? This is the "normal" way to do this sort of thing. Which is not to say it's the right way. I don't know what your ultimate objective is, you may well need model rotation rather than camera movement around an object.

Comment: @Confused If I add an object to the scene and I want to rotate just one, that doesn't work. I want to learn the proper way to rotate objects without moving the camera.

Comment: Have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834092/how-to-rotate-an-scnbox

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate the node with a gesture, it is done with respect to the node's axes. Say your node is in it's original default orientation, +X direction to the right. Now you rotate the the node 180° about the Y with a left-to-right swipe. If you now apply a top-to-bottom swipe, the node will rotate upward about the X instead of downward. This is because the first swipe swung the X-axis around such that it was pointing in the opposite direction. That's just the extreme example, if your first Y rotation was less than 180°, an attempt to now swipe about the X will cause the node to rotate in a slanted manner such as in your video.

One way to deal with this is to place your earth node in another node (a "container node"). Use the earth node for Y rotation and,separately, use the container node for the X rotation.

But the way I deal with this can be found here:  [How to rotate an SCNBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834092/how-to-rotate-an-scnbox/38838243#38838243)

Comment: In the movie that I've uploaded I didn't rotate around the y axis before starting rotating around the x axis.

Comment: I think your question needs more clarification. It's unclear how the description and video relate.

Comment: Also, have you inspected the native axis orientation of your Blender DAE within the editor?